# Why am I getting this 'no such file to load' error with rake command?

Tags: ruby, git, rake

I am working on lab 21 at [this](http://gitimmersion.com/lab_21.html) site. The directory path I have added the rakefile to is:

[image: directory path]

Now, it says I should be able to run the 'hello' program by invoking the 'rake' command from my console. However, when I enter the command I get the following back:

[image: error message]

The line in question from the rakefile is as:

```
  require './lib/hello'
```

I have followed this tutorial to the letter, so I don't believe it is a mistake with the filepath. But to be sure, I even reversed the directory names of hello and lib, like this, to be sure:

[image: different filepath]

The tutorial is on git, not rakefiles, so it's not exactly a pressing issue, but it sure is annoying to not be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both images have conflicting directory structure, not sure which one's right.  But, since your Rakefile and hello.rb are in the same directory, you need to change :

```
require ./lib/hello.rb
```

to

```
require ./hello.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're already in the `./lib` directory.  Remove `./lib` from the `require`:

`require './hello'`